# CSS: Change all elements of class "x" when specific element is hovered

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div element and I want all elements that have a certain class to change when the div is hovered. 
I just couldn't get it to work. My code is only affecting the first element of the class and no I am not using the :first-child selector...

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/f6q4080c/

```css
#hoverme {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; 
  background: blue;
}
.other {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 5px;
  background: red; 
}

#hoverme:hover + .other {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="hoverme" href="#">Hover me to turn the red ones green.</div>
    <div class="other">I want to turn green.</div>
    <div class="other">I want to turn green, too.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to target all of the siblings of a particular element, which would turn all of your `.other` elements "green" when your `hoverme` element was hovered :

```
/* This will turn all other classes green when hoverme is hovered */
#hoverme:hover ~ .other {
    background: green;
}
```

**Example**

[image]

```css
#hoverme {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.other {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: red;
}
#hoverme:hover ~ .other {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hoverme" href="#">Hover me to turn the red ones green.</div>
  <div class="other">I want to turn green.</div>
  <div class="other">I want to turn green, too.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work in the case that the the elements are not siblings?

Comment: It really depends on the use-case. CSS can handle things like children or descendants fairly well (i.e. moving down the DOM), however it doesn't support parents, so it really just depends on what you need to do.

Comment: +1 for not giving a JS solution. But please note, the CSS method works only for the `~` (sibling), `>` (descendant) and `+` (adjacent sibling) selectors.